# ((undefined method ` ' NoMethodError)) when using applitools EYES in Ruby/Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am simply trying to set a constant on the Eyes class, but I get a very strange error. It works when setting the API key, but setting any other constant (like `save_new_tests`, `host_os`, or `match_level` see [documentation](https://applitools.atlassian.net/wiki/display/Java/Selenium+-+Ruby))) gives me the error below.  I don't know what I'm doing differently than when I'm setting the API key.  Thanks for your help!

env.rb:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'eyes_selenium'

Before do |scenario|

  $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  $driver.manage.window.resize_to(1050, 900)
  @eyes = Applitools::Eyes.new
  @eyes.api_key = 'my_api_key'
  @eyes.save_new_tests = true  # <-- Errors here
  @eyes.open(app_name: 'my_app', test_name: scenario.title, driver: $driver)

end
```

Error:

```
undefined method `  ' for #<Object:0x007fdc778eb740> (NoMethodError)
./features/support/env.rb:10:in `Before'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
▶ '  '.codepoints
#⇒ [
#    [0] 8194,
#    [1] 8194
# ]
```

The above is a result of me copy-pasting the content of “undefined method” from your error description.

That said, you accidentally have entered [unicode en-space](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=8194) (possibly with <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> on MacOS, or copy-paste from some web example.) Retype the line manually and everything should work as intended.

Comment: I just copied the message directly from the terminal.  That said, when I removed the `@` form the variable, i got this error instead:

undefined local variable or method `  eyes' for #<Object:0x007fd9f542fd70> (NameError)
  ./features/support/env.rb:10:in `Before'

Comment: Please remove all leading spaces before `eyes` (from the very beginning of the line,) and retype them using your keyboard.

Comment: I removed and retyped all the spaces before `eyes` in the env.rb code, and included a screenshot of the error message.  http://imgur.com/mumWSmE.  I know it's strange, but this is the error message I'm getting.  I don't know why it looks strange.

Comment: Ah, I see.  It was the invisible unicode that was throwing me off.  Thanks a lot!